# PHP file_get_contents foreach element on the array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, file-get-contents

Is it possible to do a `file_get_contents` for each element in an array?

I have an array (`$content`) with over 300 items, the idea is to take every element in the array and do a `file_get_contents` from a different server to obtain the remaining information of that specific item.

`$content` has 300 different id items similar to these:

1. e94ab0b9
2. 73e03235

I can take one id and obtain the rest of the information for each by doing a simple `file_get_contents` which yields the price, the name, and its location, but I need it for all items. Here is what I’ve got:

```
$arr = array($content);
foreach($arr as $id) {          
echo $id, '<br>';           
$data = file_get_contents('http://mywebsite.com/central.php?a='.$id.'');
echo $data, '<br>';
}
```

This returns an empty query. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for any input or pointers.

Comment: What you are attempting should work, though it would be exceedingly slow.  What is `$content` though? You are making an array of only one element.  `print_r($arr);` to see what you started with.

Comment: if `$content` is already an array it should be `foreach($content as $id) {`

Comment: Oh, $content is an array to begin with. Don't wrap it, just loop over it directly.

Comment: $content is a simple list of over 300 items i take each item on this list and created a simple array with it.

Comment: list in what format? what does either it or the array $arr actully look like

Comment: I have a feeling you need to be doing `$arr = array_map('trim',explode("\n",$content));` and possibly more than that, depending on what format your actual list is.. for example, does your list have numbered prefixes like shown in your example?

Comment: Thank you Michael, the problem was in my array itself. And you were right is very slow, wish there was an easier (faster way..)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my array. IT is possible, it just very slow, i might go a different route. thanks to everyone for looking into this.

Comment: curl_multi would be faster

Comment: What Dagon said.  Use curl and reuse the handle and it will go much faster.